# .cod data section to large when running blackberry webworks project

Tags: blackberry, jquery-mobile, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I made a Blackberry Webworks project using jquery mobile and phonegap.  When I go to build the project I get the error "I/O error: output error: Solution-###.cod data section to large 65152 bytes".

I am under the impression that when creating a webworks project the images and resources you use and that is what is causing this error?  I have gone through and made all of my images smaller than 65 KB and right now the only things larger then 65 KB are my jquery.js, jqueryMobile.js and index.html files.

I am a little confused as to what I can do to fix this error or to figure out which Solution-97.cod?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you are getting is due to the size of the created .cod file(s).  Each of these files cannot be larger than 64kb in size.  I have not worked with webworks, I code apps with eclipse, and this splits the final app into multiple .cod files less than 64kb.

Since you have mentioned that it gets up to "solution-97.cod" I assume it is exporting to at least that number of cod files - i.e. approx 6.2mb of data.  I've found that any apps over approx. 3Mb tend to give hassles and errors with the cod file creation.

If possible try to reduce the size of your resources (convert png to jpg where possible for example).

There is a discussion (and links to further threads of a similar nature) on the blackberry developer forums: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/cod-data-section-too-large-65222/td-p/410066

Comment: After reducing the file sizes of those images it builds. I guess there were a few that were close to 64kb that still gave some issues. Thanks!